# Build an installer

Tags: .net, installation, windows-installer

I need to build an installer for my application (using Windows Installer technology - MSI file). Requirements for this installer:
1. Embed component in installer (ex: .NET Framework 4.0 Full).
2. Detect the present of this component.
3. If this component is not installed yet, installer will install it before. Installer will display a dialog with info "Installing the component ..." and the component is installed silent. If user cancel to install this component, the installer is also cancelled.
4. After installing this component successful, install the application.
Thanks.

I download Splash Lite from website: http://mirillis.com/en/downloads/downloads_splash.html. I like this installer because it matches my requirements. Because I am a newbie, anyone can give me some guides to create an installer like this. Thanks.

Some screenshot:
[image: Detect Component]

PLease help me. Thanks.

Comment: Visual Studio has the tools and templates built-in, except the Express editions.

Comment: How to begin. I am using .NET 2010 Ultimate. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio has the tools and templates built-in.

In your solution, choose Add New Project, Other Project Types, Setup, VS Installer.

Choose the Setup Wizard and follow the steps.

Comment: How to create a EXE installer which contains component and application's MSI. When run EXE installer, it will install component and install app's MSI after that. Thanks.

Comment: Lu lu, just try it. You get a Setup.Exe + MyProject.msi.  There is a prerequisites dialog somewhere for std and custom components.

Comment: You can give me the tutorial how to make it. It will create a EXE (package contains setup.exe + component.exe + project.msi). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this codeplex project: [dotNetInstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/)

worked fine for me.

Comment: That's just a bootstrapper, doesn't help for building the MSI component

Comment: Yes that's true. But look at his question: He'd like to embedd components (ex: .NET Framework 4.0 ...)